# Copy Excel cell comments in a specified range

Tags: c#, office-interop, excel-interop

What is the way to copy all cell comments (on right click - Insert Comments) in a specified range?

```
Range r1 = (Range)ws1.get_Range("A1", "C10");
Range r2 = (Range)ws2.get_Range("A1", "C10");
r2.Value = r1.Value; // copies cell values and ignores comments
```

I know that `r1.Copy(r2);` would copy values and comments, but it shows unnecessary Excel dialogs due to validation issues and therefore I cannot use it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a `AddComment` method for `Range`.  Unfortunately, it cannot be applied to a range of cells.  I guess they assumed: *why would you want the same comment written multiple times?*  So you'll have to loop:

```
for (int r = 1; r <= r1.Rows.Count; r++)
{
    for (int c = 1; c <= r1.Columns.Count; c++)
    {
        r2[r, c].AddComment(r1.Comment);
    }
}
```